# how to write delete query with multiple where conditions in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to write delete query in Yii2:

```
Yii::$app->db
->createCommand()
->delete('followusers', ['AND', 'follower' => $id[1],  'followed' => $id[0]])
->execute();
```

It's not giving the correct result I need any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Yii::$app->db
->createCommand()
->delete('followusers', ['AND', ['follower' => $id[1]],  ['followed' =>  $id[0]]])
->execute();
```